# AWS Athena and date_format

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have some issue while formatting a timestamp with Amazon Athena service.

`select date_format(current_timestamp, 'y')`

Returns just 'y' (the string).

The only way I found to format dates in Amazon Athena is trough `CONCAT` + `YEAR` + `MONTH` + `DAY` functions, like this:

`select CONCAT(cast(year(current_timestamp) as varchar), '_', cast(day(current_timestamp) as varchar))`

Comment: It is not clear what is your required result. Please add a data sample.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
select  current_timestamp

       ,date_format     (current_timestamp, '%Y_%m_%d')
       ,format_datetime (current_timestamp, 'y_M_d')
;
```

---

```
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
|        _col0        |   _col1    |   _col2   |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
| 2017-05-19 14:46:12 | 2017_05_19 | 2017_5_19 |
+---------------------+------------+-----------+
```

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: I was able to get this to work using David's second function, removing the `%`s, not the first.

Answer (score -2):

This will work as well with js, if it helps anyone...

```
const current = new Date();
date: `${current.getFullYear()}-${current.getMonth() + 1}-${current.getDate()}`
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?