# Need to convert string value in Date Format in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am new in Athena. I am facing one challenge like below:
I have a column, date value like `Nov 29, 2022 11:26:00 PM`. But I need this value as `YYYYMMDD` format in Athena either Integer or String format. Can anyone help me to convert this value.

Example:
`Nov 29, 2022 11:26:00 PM`  it should be `20221129`

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064923/aws-athena-and-date-format) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152596/amazon-athena-convert-string-to-date) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough to fully determine the original format, but in essence you need to first parse date and then format it back:

```sql
select date_format(
            date_parse('Nov 29, 2022 11:26:00 PM', '%b %d, %Y %r'),
            '%Y%m%d'
        );
```

More info on concrete format identifiers can be found [in the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) (or in [this one](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions)). Potentially you might need to change `%r` (Time, 12-hour, hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM) and maybe `%d`(Day of the month, numeric 01 .. 31).